# John The Ripper 'No password hashes loaded'

Tags: password-cracking

Please forgive the newbie question, but we all have to start somewhere, right?

Following reading this excellent [book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Basics-Hacking-Penetration-Testing-Ethical/dp/0124116442/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1453393658&sr=8-1&keywords=basics%20of%20hacking%20and%20penetration%20testing), I am trying to learn John. I've been through the [FAQ](http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/FAQ.shtml) and this [tutorial](http://hackingmanual.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/john-ripper-tutorial.html), but am stuck.

I have made a SHA256 password hash. It's super simple. The password is 'password' mixed with the salt and hashed just once. I now want to use a tool to crack it.

I've saved it to a file in a format that I think is correct (see screenshot below).

When running the following command, I get 'No password hashes loaded'

What should I do to get this working please?

```
Command: john -single passw
```

[image: Attempt at password cracking]

Comment: You should read the John the Ripper documentation:
http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/

Comment: Read the docs..

Comment: Your "hash" is a base64 string, this may explain why john doesn't recognize it, http://www.openwall.com/lists/john-users/2012/06/24/6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your hash is base64 coded. You must decode this before use john.
You can use the command :

```
base64 -d <hash>
```

If you want to be sure of the hash format, you can use :

```
hash-identifier
```